# Java Properties - can't find existing properties file

Tags: java, properties-file

I'm using the following references, since this is the first time I've used Java Properties.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html
- http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

I'm attempting to run the following at the beginning of my program start, so the user only has to select the database file path once. After selecting it once, every subsequent program run should automatically use the config.properties file and get the database path.

Unfortunately, `input == null` is continually firing on every program run, even after selecting the correct database path in the previous program run and confirming the properties file contains the database path information.

Am I doing something wrong below?

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    String filename = "config.properties";
    input = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
    if (input == null) 
    {
        fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Choose the database file");
        fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("S3DB Files", "S3DB");
        fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);

        int ret = fileChooser.showDialog(null, "Select File");
        File file = null;

        if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            dbc = new DBConnect(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        OutputStream output = null;

        try 
        {
            output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");

            // set the properties value
            prop.setProperty("database", file.getAbsolutePath());

            // save properties to project root folder
            prop.store(output, null);

        } 
        catch (IOException io) 
        {
            io.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally 
        {
            if (output != null) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    output.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            prop.load(input);
            dbc = new DBConnect(prop.getProperty("database"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString(), "Properties Read/Write Exception Occured (PRGRYADDView())", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is your `config.properties` placed

Comment: It's initially created in the folder where my JAR is.

Comment: and is that directory passed in classpath at runtime ?

Comment: It's initially created in the folder where my JAR is on the fly when my executable JAR runs for the first time. It's variable.

Comment: how do you run your application ?

Comment: Executable JAR file, double click or java -jar.

Comment: try `java -cp /path/to/your/jarFile.jar:/path/to/your/ your.launcher.class.Main`

Answer (score 0):

Check your the properties file path.

Create a 'config.properties' file, and put it in your project classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
input = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

with this:

```
try
{
    input = new FileInputStream(filename);
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

I was attempting to load from the classpath rather than from the properties file itself relative to the executable JAR. The above solved my problem.

Be sure to add in your own exception handling as well.